# PhpStorm 2018.2: filename in tab not underlined when an error is present in TypeScript

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpstorm-2018.1

After update to PhpStorm 2018.2 I've found that in my Angular project the filename in editor tab is not underlined (with red color wave) if an error is occured within that file. However the errors in code are well underlined.

Also the files containing errors on the left navigation bar are not underlined.

Same issue occures in a .js files from another project.

I've tried to remove .idea, to rename project folder but it doesn't resolve the issue.

In my php project everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've completely removed PhpStorm and reinstalled it again following this instructions: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519

Now it works fine.

Make sure you export your settings (File -> Export Settings) because they will be erased.